# How do I generate a list of dates of every 7 days between a range of dates based on a date field in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to generate a list of week end dates based on the first week end date, and between a date range.

For example:  I have a week end date of '06/04/2022'.  If I enter 06/01/2022-01/01/2023 as my date parameters, I need a list of every seven days beginning on 06/04/2022 through 01/01/2023. The output would look something like this:

| Dates |
| --- |
| 06/04/2022 |
| 06/11/2022 |
| 06/18/2022 |
| . |
| . |
| . |
| 12/24/2022 |
| 12/31/2022 |

Note: the initial week end date is not necessarily always on a Saturday, so it would need to be based on the actual date and not the day of the week.

I have this code which produces every day between two dates, but I need every seven days between two dates, and based on a date field retrieved from another table. I'm stuck on how to get every seven days, or every week from the date.

```
select (date'2022-06-04' + level - 1) dt
from   dual
connect by level <= (date'2023-01-01' - date'2022-06-01' + 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the step size by 7:

```sql
SELECT DATE '2022-06-04' + (level - 1) * 7 AS dt
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY DATE '2022-06-04' + (level - 1) * 7 <= DATE '2023-01-01'
```

Or, to make the calculation you are preforming more obvious that you are adding a week, you can use an `INTERVAL` literal:

```sql
SELECT DATE '2022-06-04' + (level - 1) * INTERVAL '7' DAY AS dt
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY DATE '2022-06-04' + (level - 1) * INTERVAL '7' DAY <= DATE '2023-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also calculate the number of weeks required in your connect by levels code.

i.e. This would give you the number of rows required

```
CONNECT BY LEVEL < (DATE2 - DATE1) / 7
```

Notably the DATE2 - DATE1 code works because Oracle likes to think of things in terms of days. i.e. Sysdate - 1 is just yesterday. Sysdate + 1 is just tomorrow.

Then tack on a + 1 since you probably want to return 1 row in the case it's less than a week

And then doing this

```
SELECT DATE'2023-01-24' + (LEVEL-1) * 7
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < ((SYSDATE - DATE'2023-01-24') / 7) + 1
```